# How can I change nickname of XMPP user in XMPPFramework?

Tags: xmpp, xmppframework

I want to change the nick name of user on my XMPP project. I am using this code but it is not working. I can change the status and ... but in changing the nick name of user, I have problem.

Anybody can help me ?

```
XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [xmppvCardTempModule myvCardTemp];
    if (!myvCardTemp)
    {
        NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
        XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML];
        [newvCardTemp setNickname:NewName];
        [xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp];
    }
    else
    {
        [myvCardTemp setNickname:NewName];

        [xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:myvCardTemp];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand for changing this, I have to change familyname instead of nickname.
So I changed this code and it is working fine.

```
XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [xmppvCardTempModule myvCardTemp];
    if (!myvCardTemp)
    {
        NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
        XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML];
        //[newvCardTemp setNickname:@"nick"];
        [newvCardTemp setFamilyName:NewName];
        [xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp];
    }
    else
    {
        //[myvCardTemp setNickname:@"nick"];
        [myvCardTemp setFamilyName:NewName];
        [xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:myvCardTemp];
    }
```

Comment: You should make this as the answer in case this is the solution to help others with same problem :)

Comment: Yes it is too late to add as answer :(